# What would be a good sampler from pymc3 for highly skewed data

Tags: bayesian, python, skewness, pymc, ab-test

I have a gamma distributed data which is highly skewed - alpha=0.15, beta=0.001.
I would like to perform mcmc to find the delta between two gamma distributions.

I get the following error:
[image]

I suspect the reason is that my data is highly skewed. What would be a good sampler to catch the skewness of my data?

Comment: You need to give us more details.